# Gatsby build fails with keycloak (@react-keycloak/web)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, keycloak

I am using Gatsby to build static site and keycloak for auth.
I am using these libs: `keycloak-js` and `@react-keycloak/web`
During development (gatsby develop) everything runs fine, auth works and all that...

But when i run `gatsby build`, it fails specifically with this error:

`WebpackError: authClient has not been assigned to ReactKeycloakProvider`

This is the react keycloak lib that i am using [@react-keycloak/web](https://github.com/react-keycloak/react-keycloak/tree/master/packages/web) and error comes from `useKeycloak.ts` file.

#### gatsby-browser.js

```
const React = require('react')
const Keycloak = require('keycloak-js')
const { ReactKeycloakProvider } = require('@react-keycloak/web') 

const kc = Keycloak({
  url: 'xxx',
  realm: 'xxx',
  clientId: 'xxx',
})

const initOptions = {
  onLoad: 'check-sso',
  silentCheckSsoRedirectUri: window.location.origin + '/silent-check-sso.html',
}

function wrapRootElement ({ element }) {
  return (
    <ReactKeycloakProvider 
      authClient={kc}
      initOptions={initOptions}
      LoadingComponent={<div>Loading...</div>}
    >
      {element}
    </ReactKeycloakProvider>
  )
}

exports.wrapRootElement = wrapRootElement
```

This is what gatsby docs suggest: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/

#### What i tried and didn't work

- Guarding my gatsby-browser.js code and wrapping it in `if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {}`
- Returning ReactKeycloakProvider only if window exists, otherwise {element}
- Using `React.lazy` to load those libs
- Using that `@loadable-components` as docs suggest
- Using either common js require and es6 import in gatsby-browser.js file
- importing libs directly inside `wrapRootElement` component
- Tried deleting node_modules, .cache, public and installing all again

Tried this in gatsby-node.js as well

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html" || stage === "develop-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [          
          {
            test: /@react-keycloak\/web/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

I am using versions:

```
"@react-keycloak/web": "^3.4.0",
"gatsby": "^3.0.1",
"keycloak-js": "^12.0.4",
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
```

I don't even know what to try anymore, it's so annoying. I even tried next js but i get totally different problems with keycloak (that server returns different stuff from the client).

Should i just not use `@react-keycloak/web` and write my own context and provider? but i mean module is working fine except during the gatsby build.

Comment: The error occurs only when useKeycloak() from @react-keycloak/web is called in any file. When i don't use that hook, the builds succeeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol apparently i all i had to do was add this code to gatsby-ssr.js

#### gatsby-ssr.js

```
const React = require('react')
const { ReactKeycloakProvider } = require('@react-keycloak/web')

function wrapRootElement ({ element }) {
  return (
    <ReactKeycloakProvider authClient={{}}>
      {element}
    </ReactKeycloakProvider>
  )
}

exports.wrapRootElement = wrapRootElement
```

So in the end i didn't have to use anything special (any loader or whatever).

#### gatsby-browser.js

```
const React = require('react')
const Keycloak = require('keycloak-js')

const { ReactKeycloakProvider } = require('@react-keycloak/web')

const kc = Keycloak({
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth',
  realm: 'test',
  clientId: 'test-web',
})

const initOptions = {
  onLoad: 'check-sso',
  silentCheckSsoRedirectUri: window.origin + '/silent-check-sso.html',
}

function wrapRootElement ({ element }) {
  return (
    <ReactKeycloakProvider 
      authClient={kc}
      initOptions={initOptions}
      LoadingComponent={<div>Loading...</div>}
    >
      {element}
    </ReactKeycloakProvider>
  )
}

exports.wrapRootElement = wrapRootElement
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`loadable-components`](https://github.com/gregberge/loadable-components)? It seems a matter of SSR...

```
const React = require('react')
const Keycloak = require('keycloak-js')
const Keycloak = loadable(() => require('keycloak-js'))
const {ReactKeycloakProvider} = loadable(() => require('@react-keycloak/web'))

const kc = Keycloak({
  url: 'xxx',
  realm: 'xxx',
  clientId: 'xxx',
})

const initOptions = {
  onLoad: 'check-sso',
  silentCheckSsoRedirectUri: window.location.origin + '/silent-check-sso.html',
}

function wrapRootElement ({ element }) {
  return (
    <ReactKeycloakProvider 
      authClient={kc}
      initOptions={initOptions}
      LoadingComponent={<div>Loading...</div>}
    >
      {element}
    </ReactKeycloakProvider>
  )
}

exports.wrapRootElement = wrapRootElement
```

Notice that you can also try adding a `null` loader to both dependencies, rather than one, just to check.

Comment: Yeah i tried multiple null loaders it's the same error. I tried loadable-components but then it cant even run in dev an says: Uncaught TypeError: Keycloak is not a function. I tried React.lazy()/ loadable-components with .then(module => module) but didn't work also. It's some trash error with ssr yeah

Comment: Sometimes when this approach fails, it's not caused by the package itself but by a dependency of it